# How does Gibbs free energy changes if $-SdT+VdP=0$?

Tags: thermodynamics

$U=TS-PV$, then $dU=TdS+SdT-PdV-VdP$.

Also we know that $dU=TdS-PdV$ so it follows $SdT-VdP=0$.
However,$dG=-SdT+VdP$ so it should be $dG=0$.

So it looks like $G$ is always constant for a closed mono-phasic system. Is it true?

Comment: What makes you doubt that it is not the case?

Comment: If you define it like that (without the chemical potential) then not only it is constant, but it is always $0=U-TS+pV=G$.